# C++ Multiplying elements in a vector

Tags: c++, c++11

I have been looking for a more optimal solution to the following and I cannot seem to find one.

Let's say I have a vector:

`std::vector<double> vars = {1, 2, 3}`

I want to perform `1 * 2 * 3` I know that I can do the following:

```
int multi = 1;

for(int i = 0; (i < vars.size()-1); i++)
{
    multi *= vars[i];
}
```

But, is there a more "C++11" way to do this? I really wanted to do this using `lambda` and so that I can calculate the multiply (product) of the vector without having another function inside the class, I'd rather have it calculated inside the function.

Comment: Your code computes `v[0]*v[0]*v[1]*v[2]*...*v[n-2]`, i.e. `v[0]` is multiplied twice and `v[n-1]` is forgotten.

Comment: Not sure what your intent is, but if you planned on multiplying all elements of the vector, you dont need -1 in **vars.size()-1**

Comment: You may have not expected result by multiplying `int` and `double`.

Comment: `multi` should be `double` here and  `i < vars.size()`.  As for "C++ way" there is a template `std::accumulate` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate Usually it's best for more generic cases.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

### C++98

Yes, as usual, there is an algorithm (though this one's in `<numeric>`), `std::accumulate` ([live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3abff4b1a0debde1)):

```
using std::begin;
using std::end;
double multi = std::accumulate(begin(vars), end(vars), 1.0, std::multiplies<double>());
```

`std::multiplies` is in `<functional>`, too. By default, `std::accumulate` uses `std::plus`, which adds two values given to `operator()`. `std::multiplies` multiplies them instead.

### C++23

The C++23 ranges version of this function is `std::ranges::fold_left`. In addition, CTAD and improvements to the standard "operator objects" have made them nicer to use:

```
namespace rng = std::ranges;
auto multi = rng::fold_left(vars, 1.0, std::multiplies());
```

As a side note, C++17 also added `std::reduce`, which is permitted to do operations out of order for speed. There is currently no ranges version of this.

Comment: I knew there was an algorithm, I think I looked at this one and I'm sure that the example given used this for calculating multiplying two separate vectors. Thank you

Comment: @Phorce, Depending on what the result of multiplying two vectors should look like, `std::transform` can also be useful. It would generate a sequence of the products of each sequential pair of elements.

Comment: Note that there's no c++11 in this answer (except for `auto`). Not that it's a bad thing.

Comment: `std::multiplies<>()` interesting.... okay so if `operator()` is templated to do the deduction, what sort of beast is this `std::multiplies<>` instance that's created beforehand?

Comment: Why the `using std::begin; using std::end`? Since you have a `std::vector` ADL will find the correct overload. You don't even need the `std::` in `std::accumulate` either.

Comment: This is nice and very 'C++y', but does one more multiplication than necessary (since it computes `1*v[0]*...`). Moreover, it uses `operator*` rather than `*=`, which for some types may be slower (though hardly for builtin types).

Comment: @templateboy, You're right, it's more of a consistency thing, like `using std::swap;` in a `swap` member function even when your class doesn't contain anything but built-in types. I prefer not to use ADL for regular function calls in general.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, To my knowledge, these functors got their type defaulted to `void` and the specialization for `void` differs just in the templating on `operator()`. Theoretically, it could just be `std::multiplies()`, but that would break code.

Comment: @Walter, True, if you cared enough about the extra initial multiplication, you could replace `1` with the first element and start at `std::next(begin(vars))`. As for the use of `*`, I think it would be possible to make a functor that takes the accumulator by reference.

Comment: @chris: Aha! So it's `std::multiplies<void>()` in fact. Makes sense.

Comment: Note that this causes unexpected integer overflow if he wants `double multi` instead of `int multi`.

Use `std::accumulate(begin(vars), end(vars), (double)1, std::multiplies<double>())` instead.

See the "common mistakes" part of [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate).

Comment: But whatif the input `vars` happens to be empty? This solution will return 1, but expected answer should be 0.

Comment: @StayFoolish, The mathematically correct answer for the product of an empty set is 1. 0 is the identity for addition of numbers, but not for multiplication. If the logic has a constraint that requires 0 in this case, the code needs a separate check for empty input.

Answer (score 7):

You can use a ranged based for loop like:

```
std::vector<double> vars = {1, 2, 3}
int multi = 1;

for (const auto& e: vars)
    multi *= e;
```

Comment: I know you from DaniWeb! (I'm sure you are the same guy) thank you for your answer!

Comment: @Phorce:  Yes I am on DaniWeb under the same name.  I started on here a couple months ago because DaniWeb was starting to get stale.  No problem with the help on your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is using `inclusive_scan` (C++17 and above)

The advantage is you can get multiplies of first "N" elements in a vector.
Below is the code. Explanation in comments.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    //INPUT VECTOR
    std::vector<int> data{ 3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6 };

    //OUTPUT VECTOR WITH MULTIPLIES
    //FIRST ELEMENT - 3 
    //SECOND ELEMENT - 3 * 1 
    //THIRD ELEMENT - 3 * 1 * 4 
    //FOURTH ELEMENT - 3 * 1 * 4 * 1
    // ..
    // ..
    //LAST ELEMENT - 3 * 1 * 4 * 1 * 5 * 9 * 2 * 6
    std::vector<int> multiplies(data.size());

    //Multiply all numbers in given vector.
    inclusive_scan(data.begin(), data.end(),
        multiplies.begin(),
        std::multiplies<>{});

    //PRODUCT OF FIRST 5 ELEMENTS.
    std::cout << "Product of first 5 elements :: " << multiplies[4] << std::endl;

    //PRODUCT OF ALL ELEMENTS
    std::cout << "Product of all elements :: " << multiplies[data.size() - 1] << std::endl;
}
```

Also there is an overload where the execution policy can be specified.
Sequential execution or Parallel execution. Need to include "execution" header.

```
//MULTIPLY ALL NUMBERS IN VECTOR WITH PARALLEL EXECUTION.
inclusive_scan(std::execution::par,data.begin(), data.end(),
    multiplies.begin(),
    std::multiplies<>{});
```