# How to find the product of vector elements?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, product, stdvector

I have the following vector values: `[2, 3, 7]`.

I want to output the product of the vector, as in `2*3*7 = 42`.

I wrote some code for it but it doesn't appear to be working. I am new to C++, so I am not sure how to get the product of the values in a vector given any numeric vector of any size.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<int> vec;
    while (n--) 
    {
        int temp;
        cin >> temp;
        vec.push_back(temp);
    }
    int total = 1;
    total *= vec;
    cout << vec << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you wanted to print the values in the vector how would you do that?

Comment: You have to access each member of `vec` individually. While the class may be called `vector`, it's name has more to do with the "shape" of the structure, and isn't designed to be handled like a mathematical "vector", or as a 1-dimensional matrix.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ Multiplying elements in a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29146175/c-multiplying-elements-in-a-vector)  The technique uses `std::accumulate` and `std::multiplies`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the product of **any numeric vector of any size**, here's a function that works with any numeric type of vector with the help of templates:

```
template <class any>
long double vectorProduct(vector<any> vec) {
  long double total = 1;

  for(any num : vec) {
    total *= num;
  }

  return total;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
cout << vectorProduct(vec) << endl;
```

Comment: At the level the OP is, you could drop the `template` and use `int` instead of `any`. Good answer, but might have a bit of a learning curve ;-)

Comment: A generic solution should take into account that taking the product will overflow easily, hence the return type should perhaps not be `any`. And I agree with Jeffrey, the solution is probably a bit too far for what OP needs

Comment: I dont know. I am just saying that it requires a more well tought design if you are really aiming for " any numeric vector of any size"

Comment: worked fine, thanks!

Comment: I changed the return type to `long double` to better account for overflows and decimal values.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that this is reimplementing `std::accumulate`. In addition, it you were to use a templated approach, `for(any num : vec)` implies many copies which may be significant for user provided types.

Comment: I would have written this with `any` in place of `long double` to let the product be the same type as its operands.  Then it works when you provide a complex number or a matrix or something a little more exotic as the type.

Comment: I'd pass the vector by `const` reference.

Comment: I would not name template `any`, too confusing with `std::any`. generic `T` is fine.

Comment: `long double total = 1;` would be better as `any total = static_cast<any>(1);` - if I multiply integers I probably don't want a float in return.

Comment: How about letting the caller choose the return type? with a default of any or better some decltype(declval<any>() * declval<any>()). Note that this will make it even more similar to how std::accumulate works

Answer (score 8):

Using [`std::accumulate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate), one can do

```
#include <numeric>    // std::accumulate
#include <functional> // std::multiplies

const auto total = std::accumulate(vec.cbegin(), vec.cend(), 1, std::multiplies<int>{});
```

---

By wrapping into a templated function, the code would be more generic

```
template<typename Type>
auto product(const std::vector<Type>& vec, Type init)
{
    return std::accumulate(vec.cbegin(), vec.cend(), init, std::multiplies<Type>{});
}
```

and call it with

```
const auto total = product(vec, /*value to be initialized/ started with*/);
```

Comment: Be careful when using `1`.  If the type is not `int` then the results may not be correct.

Comment: @NathanOliver Then it's should be generic. Let me update.

Comment: @NathanOliver You are indeed correct that the return type is based on the type of the initial value for the accumulate.  I was wrong.  I deleted my comment, so it doesn't become misinformation.  Thanks for pointing that out.  Your cautionary note is well noted!

Comment: @Wyck No problem.  It's why I left it as it tends to trip lots of people up.

Answer (score 3):

Try multiplying each value inside the vector.

```cpp
for(std::size_t i=0; i<vec.size(); i++) {
  total *= vec[i];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

With std, you might use [`std::accumulate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate):

```
int product(const std::vector<int>& v)
{
    return std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 1, std::multiplies<>{});
}
```

Comment: Be careful when using `1`.  If the type is not `int` then the results may not be correct.

Comment: Indeed, as for `std::accumulate` with `std::plus`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would do for your example:

```
#include <iostream>
int main ()
{
  int n;
  std::cin >> n;
  int total = 1;
  while(n--) {
    int temp;
    std::cin >> temp;
    total *= temp;
  }
  std::cout << "Total: " << total << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution uses [`std::accumulate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) with the operator [`std::multiplies`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/multiplies) to accumulate all elements by multiplying them. By just modifying your code, the end result would be:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

int main() {
    int n; 
    std::cin >> n;
    std::vector<int> vec;
    while(n--) {
        int temp;
        std::cin >> temp;
        vec.push_back(temp);
    }

    int result = std::accumulate(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec), 1, std::multiplies<int>()); 
    std::cout << result << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

You were not processing the vector at all, and also outputting the vector but not the total result.